# Execute jQuery code when page loads for first time and then after time period

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a piece of jQuery code and I need to execute when page load for first time, then I need to execute the same code after 30 minutes (less take this value as example) of course if page is open. I know how to execute code every 30 minutes by using this:

```
window.setInterval(function() {
    ...
    });
}, 1800000); // Updates each 30 minutes
```

But which is the best approach to do this, I mean execute code first time page loads and then every 30 minutes, do I explain myself?

Comment: 30 minutes is an *awfully* long time to be keeping a page active. This sounds like a bad solution to a problem. Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(window).load(function () {
    function func() {
        //code here
    }
    func(); // call the function window.load 
    window.setInterval(func, 1800000); // also set setInterval to run function func .
});
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function func() {
        //code here
    }
    func(); // call the function window.load 
    window.setInterval(func, 1800000); // also set setInterval to run function func .
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Put your function into a name func:

```
function blah() {
...
}
```

Then call it:

```
window.setInterval(blah, 18000000);
blah();
```

Answer (score 0):

Or just

```
(function() {
    // Your code

    // Then call itself again
    setTimeout(arguments.callee, 18000000);
})()
```